# tf.math.add raises error depending on environment

Tags: python, tensorflow

currently I am writing a function for tensorflow to calculate states for a board game.  I tested the function in eager-mode and decorated it with `@tf.function` in order to speed up.  On my laptop, the functions works as expected in both cases, but as soon as I switch to the server (for both, GPU and CPU usage) an error occurs stating that the array dimensions do not fit.

Here is the part of the code, that results in an error:

```
TF_MOVEDIRECTIONS = tf.constant(
    [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [-1, -1], [0, -1]],
    dtype=tf.int64)


@tf.function
def tf_calculations_nonlosing(bstate):
    new_states = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int64,
                                size=0,
                                dynamic_size=True,
                                infer_shape=True,
                                clear_after_read=False)
    ns_idx = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)

    # bstate is a tf.Tensor with shape = (11, 11)
    empty = tf.where(bstate == 0)
    whites = tf.where(bstate == 1)  # the shape does not fit?
    blacks = tf.where(bstate == 2)
    for move_idx in tf.range(tf.shape(TF_MOVEDIRECTIONS)[0]):
        md = TF_MOVEDIRECTIONS[move_idx]

        new_pos_w1 = tf.expand_dims(whites+md, axis=1)  # error results from this line

        ...
```

The error raised is:

`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 0 and 2 for '{{node while/add_1}} = AddV2[T=DT_INT64](while/add_1/Where_1, while/strided_slice_1) with input shapes: [?, 0] and [2]`

The strange thing is: When I test `whites = tf.where(bstate == 1)` the resulting shape always is [?, 2].  And as written above, the code works on my laptop in a jupyter notebook. Therefore, I do not understand, what the source of the error is.  I compared the tensorflow versions and they are both 2.7.0. Now I have no clue, what else might be the source of this error, and I did not even find a point where to start.

Did anybody encounter a similar error? Or does someone have an idea how to fix this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Is your question is that why output shape is None?

The 'tf.where' output shape is [the number of True, input's rank].
for example,

```
# (, 4): input's total rank is 1
input = [True, False, False, True]
# (2, 1): (True 2, input rank 1)
output = tf.where(input).numpy()
array([[0], [3]])
```

If you want to know in detail, please refer to this.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where

but when you use a TensorFlow function, the eager execution changes into TensorFlow graph operation.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function

So, although True not in bstate.shape is [11, 11], the output shape will be None that means a dynamic shape.

Comment: tf.where returns the positions of True-values, so for a 2D-tensor, the shape is (None, 2). You can test this.  That is why I do not understand the error.  Also the code works well within a different environment.

Comment: So, the code does not work on Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: The code works on Jupyter Notebook (and my laptop in general). But I want to run the code on a server within a Container and on a GPU, but within this container, the code does not work.  So I think, the environment is the problem, but I could not find any reason or help why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue finally on my own. It had nothing to do with the function at all.

I just messed up the input and that caused this error in the second place.
I did not find this, because the other functions, which were called before, managed to run with this erroneous input, so I failed to check this for quite a while.